# jQuery UI sortable - allow dropping to parent

Tags: jquery

How can I make it so a jQuery UI sortable that allows dragging between different lists, will also accept being dropped on a parent?

See [this example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/odupi5/4), where there are 3 lists, one of them empty. When dragging any list item, and dropping it on the `<div>` elements that wrap the lists (green), I want that item to go to the end of the contained `<ul>` (red). The sortable's `update` function needs to be called automatically as well. How?

```
$('.sortable').sortable(
{ 
  accept: '.sortable li', 
  connectWith: '.sortable,.container',
  update: function () { alert('done with the moving'); }
});
```

My attempt (doesn't work) is to make the containing `<div>` a droppable target, as follows:

```
$('.container').droppable(
{
  accept: '.sortable li',
  drop: function(event, ui)
  {
    ui.draggable.appendTo($(this).find('ul'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by cloning the helper element and then removing the original element from the DOM.

Note, you have to clear the style attribute as it has `position:absolute` set for dragging and this prevents the clone from positioning correctly in the `ul`. Of course you could be more granular about this and add/remove classes etc.

```
$('.container').droppable(
{
  accept: '.sortable li',
  drop: function(event, ui)
  {
    ui.draggable.clone().attr("style", "").appendTo( $(this).find("ul") );
    ui.draggable.remove();
  }
});
```

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/odupi5/7/edit) an updated JSBin example.